# WebService Jax WS compile but unaccessable

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, soap

I recover a project. The project is successfully deployed on tomcat but I can't test the web service or can't reach it. When I Wrote the URL I got Error 404.

The web service looks like :

```
@WebService(serviceName = "OfficialDate",
            portName = "OfficialDatePort",
            endpointInterface = "com.????.web.officialdates_v1.OfficialDate",
            targetNamespace = "http://????/web/officialDates-v1",
            wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/OfficialDateWebService/officialdates.wsdl")
```

How can I debug the WebService ? What in a webservice can do this error ?

(Sorry I can't paste code -because it is private-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional libraries (jar files) and web.xml configuration in order to host JAX-WS web services in Tomcat.

It's far easier to use a complete Java EE implementation such as WildFly, TomEE, Glassfish, etc. Your web service will just work when deployed in any of these.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear, I test the project in glassfish first, and then tomcat

Comment: What version of GlassFish?

Comment: I run on glassfish. Its the same problem, the app is deployed, but no ressources found